# Web dev-frameworks, compatible with .net 3.5 +

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, .net-3.5, frameworks

For someone, new to .Net based Web development: what web development frameworks are provided with or are compatible with .Net framework 3.5 +.

Like

- [ASP.NET Web Forms pattern](http://www.asp.net/(S(dyxuof45njejhvzszshgzy45))/downloads/essential/)
- [ASP.NET MVC framework / pattern (1.0, 2.0)](http://www.asp.net/mvc/download/)

can you provide links as well

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MonoRail http://www.castleproject.org/monorail

Answer (score 1):

A number of frameworks/apps are included with the [Microsoft Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/Downloads/platform.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

These are just a few that I've come across:

- ASP.NET MVC
- ASP.NET AJAX
- Castle Monorail
- OpenRasta
- Spring.NET: Spring.Web and Spring.Web.Extensions

Answer (score 1):

[Fubu Mvc](http://github.com/darthfubumvc/fubumvc)